# Should the race-condition tag exist? Should this question have that tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

I recently asked [Is the action of accepting a pull request on Github vulnerable to race conditions?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/116170/is-the-action-of-accepting-a-pull-request-on-github-vulnerable-to-race-condition), and while composing the question I noticed that the [race-condition](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/race-condition) tag hadn't been created yet (which surprised me) so I added that tag and created it. I also did a search and edited a couple questions to include the tag where I thought it was fit, but stopped myself since I was unsure if tagging all the relevant questions would spam the review queue (see [When and how to create new tags](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/when-and-how-to-create-new-tags)). Both of those edits have been accepted, but [an edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/revisions/116170/2) was made to *my* question which removed [race-condition](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/race-condition). I feel as though the topic of race-conditions relates heavily to my question, but I doubt it was removed on accident, and since I cannot fathom why it was removed I cannot know whether it was a good or bad reason.

Should my question have the [race-condition](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/race-condition) tag?