# How to handle very niche tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

If i come a cross a post that have a very niche, and probably new, but still relevant tag, how should I handle it? I mean for situation where we cant reasonably expect lots of questions in that category.

Can to mind when I saw the question "[Is there any existing attempted implementation of GSS-API/SPNEGO/GSS-SPNEGO for anything other than Kerberos / NTLM?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213418/is-there-any-existing-attempted-implementation-of-gss-api-spnego-gss-spnego-for)" and the tag [spnego](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/spnego/)

Edit the wiki to provide information (which i did in this case)? Try to re-tag, or straight up remove the tag?

This is basically a question about the opposite situation from "[When and how to create new tags](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/when-and-how-to-create-new-tags)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!

Personally, I think that niche tags are not a problem. They are usually for a specific product or piece of software and hence very clearly defined. If we never get more than three questions in that tag, it's still three questions that will be easy to find for anyone interested in that specific thing.

If there's only one question tagged after X months (maybe 6 or 12?) the roomba will autodelete the tag. I don't see any point in making a ruling in advance of that.

The real problems are vague and duplicate tags that don't really mean anything or add anything new. These could usualy apply to loads of questions, depending on how you subjectively interpret them. I keep an eye on the new tags page and delete some of these, would be happy if more people did.

So I think you did the right thing in keeping the tag and adding the wiki!